# find the value of x in polynomial c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> coefficients;
    cout << "Enter the polynomial coefficients (increasing degree): ";
    string line;
    getline(cin,line);
    istringstream input_string(line);

    double coefficient;
    while (input_string >>coefficient)
    {
        coefficients.push_back(coefficient);
    }

    double x;
    cout <<"Enter the x value: ";
    cin >> x;

    double value = 0,power_x = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i++)
    value += coefficients[i] * power_x;
    power_x *= x;


    cout << "The value of the polynomial at x = " << x << " is " << value << endl;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Hey guys, writing a program to calculate the value of x for a polynomial with increasing degree, here's my program and my prof wants me to enter the following as inputs:
1 0 1 for the coefficients 
1.5 for the value of x 
but my output gives me 2 instead of 3.25 which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

`power_x *= x;` is out of your for loop, so it's executed once only when you expect it to be executed for every iteration.

You need to write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i++)
{
    value += coefficients[i] * power_x;
    power_x *= x;
}
```

Then on first iteration you get `value = 1*1` and `power_x` becomes `1.5`, second iteration, value is unchanged (incremented by `0*1.5`), `power_x` becomes `1.5*1.5`, third iteration, value is incremented by `1*1.5*1.5`.

Total is then `1+1.5*1.5`, equal to `3.25`.

Debugging your code step by step using a debugger would probably have spotted this faster than stackoverflow...